# Selecting related foreignkeys in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Say I have two models, Article and Category:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='articles')

class Category(models.Model):
    ...
```

When I run `Category.objects.select_related()`, the ORM does not select the articles. I realize it's because of the way the foreignkey is shuffled around, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing, at the advice of the kind people on #django:

```
articles = Article.objects.select_related()
categories = {}

for article in articles:
    if not categories.get(article.category, None):
        categories[article.section] = []
    categories[article.category].append(article)
```